# GitLab pipeline e2e test in docker container fails

Tags: angular, docker, gitlab-ci, pipeline

```
 [11:05:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
 [11:05:45] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
 [11:05:45] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
   (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
   (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Linux 4.19.78-coreos x86_64)
 [11:05:45] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
   (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
   (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Linux 4.19.78-coreos x86_64)
     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
     at parseHttpResponse (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
     at /builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
 From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
     at Function.createSession (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
     at Function.createSession (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
     at Direct.getNewDriver (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
     at Runner.createBrowser (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
     at /builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
     at _fulfilled (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
     at /builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
     at /builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
     at runSingle (/builds/raphael.brunn3r/tqranalytics/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
 [11:05:45] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I get this error but i can't figure out how to fix it. it works locally but when i push it to gitlab and try to run the tests in a docker container (image trion/ng-cli-karma:8.3.25) it fails. below you can find my yml file.

```
image: trion/ng-cli-karma:${CLI_VERSION}

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

variables:  
  CLI_VERSION: 8.3.25

run_tests:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: false
  before_script:
    - npm ci
    - google-chrome --version
  script:
    - ng test --progress false --watch false
    - ng e2e -c=mock
  only:
    - development
    - master
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - .dist/
  tags:
  - docker
```

Comment: Can you try to update to the latest image version? There were some versions in the past with a crashing chrome.

Comment: i will try it. thank you

Comment: You're welcome - feel free to a comment if it does (not) work.